# react-page-scroll

Tags: reactjs, прокрутка

использую библиотеку react-page-scroll нужно остановить скролл когда юзер доскролил до определённого блока а потом снова продолжить но я ни как не могу найти атрибут который помог бы остановить скролл, у библиотеки нет документации только репозитории в hitHub [ссылка на репозитории](https://github.com/elhariri/react-page-scroll)